# Routing Error - No route matches "/"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

new to Ruby on Rails, trying to configure the home page of my application. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or how to configure the `:home` controller, but I get this error with this routes.rb file.

```
Routing Error - No route matches "/"
```

Here's routes.rb

```
SchoolCMS::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :teachers, :admin

  resources :home, :only => :index

  resources :admin, :only => :index

  resources :events do
    resources :event
  end

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end  

end
```

This is my home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

end
```

If I'm going about this all wrong, it would be great if you could recommend some resources I could read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need this:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do. Thank you! 6 minutes and I'll accept your answer.